# Calculating % from a char value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to calculate what proportion of my data are male and what proportion are female.

I have the following code:

```
select 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(Gender) as perc_male,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT (Gender) as perc_female
From [my_table]
```

However when running this I get 0%. Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: I'm using SQL-server - have just updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I think value is less than 1 that's why you are getting 0
try like below

```
select 
SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(Gender)*1.00
 as perc_male,
SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT (Gender)*1.00 
as perc_female
From [my_table]
```

or use explicit cast in float datatype

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
select 
SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = 'M' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) / COUNT(Gender)
as perc_male,
SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = 'F' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) / COUNT (Gender) 
as perc_female
From [my_table]
```

You are using integers. When dealing with integers, SQL always tries to return integers, which is the case here - ot rounds down to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use an explicit cast of one of the values to get the desired precision, for example

```
select 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / cast(COUNT(Gender) as decimal(5,3)) as perc_male,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / cast(COUNT(Gender) as decimal(5,3)) as perc_female
From [my_table]
```

Comment: Just looked up CAST, so that converts the gender variable to a decimal, what does the 5,3 mean in this case?

Comment: @Mrmoleje, no it converts COUNT().

Comment: But why can you not just use count like the example posted in the answer below? I'm an R user, and that would just count the number of rows that have a gender, so I'm not sure what cast does?

Comment: @Mrmoleje, `CAST` ensures sqlserver will use decimal arithmetic when dividing. Your original query will use integer arithmetic: `int /int` == `int` . Not suitable for % . You need `int/decimal` == `decimal`

Comment: Okay I get it, thanks. Does the 5,3 mean the number can be like 10000.333?

Comment: Yes, 10.333  is how the divider wil be casted. After division the result will have  greater precision. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Okay thank you, will have a look at the link as well

Answer (score 0):

The problem is integer division.  I think the simplest method is to use `AVG()`:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN Gender = 'M' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) as perc_male,
       AVG(CASE WHEN Gender = 'F' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) as perc_female
FROM [my_table]
```